# Renewing my Shahada

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, practical-islam, shirk, islamic-basis

I repeated a joke of a Muslim joking with a passenger on a plane to scare him saying Allah Akbarnow I feel like it was prohibited do I renew my shahada or just continue to ask for forgiveness

Answer (score 0):

If you harm someone, you should ask for pardon from them before you seek forgiveness from Allah. But sometimes it is not possible to seek pardon as they might be dead or you have no access to that person. Then in that case only way for you to seek forgiveness from Allah. Harming some one doesn't mean you are out of Islam, so the question of renewing shahada do not come. But still we are always renewing shahada in every salaath (prayer).